# Помогите исправить код Python

Tags: python

Вот сама задача
Год делится на четыре сезона: зима, весна, лето и осень. Хотя даты смены
сезонов каждый год могут меняться из-за особенностей календаря, мы
в данном упражнении примем допущения, перечисленные в табл. 2.9.

```
Таблица 2.9. Даты смены сезонов
Сезон Первый день
Весна 20 марта
Лето 21 июня
Осень 22 сентября
Зима 21 декабря
```

Разработайте программу, запрашивающую у пользователя день и месяц – сначала месяц в текстовом варианте, затем номер дня. На выходе
программа должна выдать название сезона, которому принадлежит выбранная дата.

```
mon=input('Введите мясяц с большой буквы')
if mon=='Январь':
    mon=1
elif mon=='Февраль':
    mon=2
elif mon=='Март':
    mon=3
elif mon=='Апрель':
    mon=4
elif mon=='Май':
    mon=5
elif mon=='Июнь':
    mon=6
elif mon=='Июль':
    mon=7
elif mon=='Август':
    mon=8
elif mon=='Сентябрь':
    mon=9
elif mon=='Октябрь':
    mon=10
elif mon=='Ноябрь':
    mon=11
elif mon=='Декабрь':
    mon=12
day=int(input('Введите номерь дня'))
if mon>=3 and day>=20:
    print('Весна')
elif mon==4:
    print('Весна')
elif mon==5:
    print('Весна')
elif mon==6 and day<=20:
    print('весна')
elif mon>=6 and day>=21:
    print('Лето')
elif mon==7:
    print('Лето')
elif mon==8:
    print('Лето')
elif mon==9 and day<=21:
    print('Лето')
elif mon>=9 and day>=22:
    print('Осень')
elif mon==10:
    print('Осень')
elif mon==11:
    print('Осень')
elif mon==12 and day<=20:
    print('Осень')
elif mon==12 and day>=21:
    print('Зима')
elif mon==1:
    print('Зима')
elif mon==2:
    print('Зима')
elif mon==3 and day<=19:
    print('Зима')
```

Comment: А что с кодом не так?

Answer (score 2):

```py
if mon>=3 and day>=20:
    print('Весна')
...
elif mon>=6 and day>=21: # никогда не сработает!
    print('Лето')
...
elif mon>=9 and day>=22: # никогда не сработает!
    print('Осень')
...
elif mon==12 and day>=21: # никогда не сработает!
    print('Зима')
```

Основная проблема с таким кодом в том, что в случаях, когда должны сработать второй, третий или четвёртый `if`, они никогда не сработают, потому что при этих условиях сработает первый `if` и до них очередь просто не дойдёт. Эту проблему можно решить либо проверяя в каждом `if` оба конца интервала, а не только нижнюю границу. Либо переставить проверки так, чтобы месяца проверялись сначала старшие, а потом уже младшие.

С проверками, где `day<=`, примерно всё тоже самое.

Answer (score -1):

```
months = {
    'Январь': 1,
    'Февраль': 2,
    'Март': 3,
    'Апрель': 4,
    'Май': 5,
    'Июнь': 6,
    'Июль': 7,
    'Август': 8,
    'Сентябрь': 9,
    'Октябрь': 10,
    'Ноябрь': 11,
    'Декабрь': 12
}

mon = input('Введите месяц с большой буквы: ')
mon_num = months[mon]
day = int(input('Введите номер дня: '))

if mon_num in [12, 1, 2] or (mon_num == 3 and day < 20):
    season = 'Зима'
elif mon_num in [3, 4, 5] or (mon_num == 6 and day <= 20):
    season = 'Весна'
elif mon_num in [6, 7, 8] or (mon_num == 9 and day <= 22):
    season = 'Лето'
else:
    season = 'Осень'

print('Сезон:', season)
```

Оптимизировал код.

Comment: Минус не мой. Лучше бы `day <` везде одинаково делать, а не "тут `<`, а там `<=`". Ну и как прошлый ответ - медвежья услуга, без пояснений для новичка.

Comment: А теперь проверь и исправь.